# Probability bounds

Tags: probability, measure-theory, integral-inequality, functional-inequalities

My question is the following:
if my random variable $X$ has finite or bounded second moment $\mathbb{E}[X^2]\leq B$ can anyone develop any bounds on pdf of $X$.

For example something like this $f(x)\leq g(B)$  where $g(.)$ is function of the bound B.

Comment: You won't be able to give such bounds, as the moments only depend on the $L^p$-Norms. So no point-wise estimates can be achieved.

Comment: What about using Chebyshev inequality and alike?

Comment: Dear @ArashBeh : A brief and [totally off topic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/and+the+like) bit of advice about what you really should write instead of "and alike." Native speakers might not recognize what you mean, so it's just FYI. I don't mean to offend or anything. Cheers

Comment: @rschwieb, Thanks for the correction! cheers!

Answer (score 0):

All you can get is
$$B \leq \mathbb{E}(X^2) = \int_\Omega x^2 f(x) d\mu(x) \leq \sup_{x\in\Omega} |x|^2 \int_\Omega f(x) d\mu(x) = C_\Omega \Vert f\Vert_{L^1(\Omega; \mu)}$$